# Recompose mapPropsToStream typescript

Tags: typescript, rxjs, recompose

I'm trying to write component on typescript that will replace onChange from props with rxjs implementation onChange, like this

```
        this.onChangeSubscription = this.onChange$
        .debounceTime(200)
        .filter(value => value.length !== 1)
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .subscribe(value => this.props.onChange(value))
```

There is an error, when I try to use pluck function:

*Property 'pluck' does not exist on type Subscribable<'Props'>*

```
     const Filter = mapPropsStream<Props,Props>((props$) => {    
            const a = props$.pluck('onChange');
            // newProps created
            return newProps$;
        })(Component);
```

Import contains

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/pluck';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using RxJS, but `recompose` is not opinionated regarding an observable implementation and [can be configured](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/docs/API.md#setobservableconfig) to work with numerous other libraries.

Even with that configuration in place, TypeScript will see `props$` as a non-RxJS type. To solve the problem, you can could use a specific type assertion  or you could use the RxJS `from` function:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/from';

const Filter = mapPropsStream<Props,Props>((props$) => {    
    const a = Observable.from(props$).pluck('onChange');
    // newProps created
    return newProps$;
})(Component);
```

Comment: And how to be with `return props$.combineLatest`?

Comment: Use `Observable.from` anytime you need to obtain an RxJS observable from the `props$` you receive from `recompose`.

Comment: this still produce a tsc error : `TS2345: Argument of type 'Subscribable<{}>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ObservableInput<ObservableInput<{}>>'.
  Property 'then' is missing in type 'Subscribable<{}>' but required in type 'PromiseLike<ObservableInput<{}>>'`